# Make formula work with xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet

Tags: angular, excel, angularjs, export, xlsx

I am trying to create an excel file in an Angular project.
For this I am using the xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet method.

I managed to populate my excel file, and now I want to add a formula in a cell.

I tried :

```
I. As a text
```

`H: '="Total : "&ROUND(100*(SUM(I16:I104)/8+SUM(J16:J104));1)&" %, "&ROUND(SUM(I16:I104)+SUM(J16:J104)*8;1)&" hours."'`
=> It displays the text of the formula, I have to click in the cell, and then press enter for the formula to be executed.

```
II. As a formula
```

`worksheet['H10'] = { f: '"Total : "&ROUND(100*(SUM(I16:I104)/8+SUM(J16:J104));1)&" %, "&ROUND(SUM(I16:I104)+SUM(J16:J104)*8;1)&" hours."' };`
=> There is a pop up error when I open the excel file, telling me there are erros in the file, when it opens, the H10 cell is empty

```
III. A little part of the formula
```

`worksheet['H10'] = { f: '100*(SUM(I16:I104)/8+SUM(J16:J104))' };`
=> There is a pop up error when I open the excel file, telling me there are erros in the file, when it opens, it displays #NAME? in the H10 cell. I have to click in it and press enter for the formula to be executed.

```
IV. A larger part of the formula
```

`worksheet['H10'] = { f: 'ROUND(100*(SUM(I16:I104)/8+SUM(J16:J104));1)' };`
=> Like with the whole formula

Does anyone has an idea of what I'm missing here ?

Thanks for your help !